# Sendtoaddress using custom private key

Tags: private-key

Let's say the user sends me his private key. What is the appropriate RPC command to spend the Bitcoins of this user using his private key?

Should I import his private key in the wallet before?

Comment: Note that under any normal circumstances, you should never send/receive a private key. It kinda defeats the purpose of having public key cryptography.

Comment: Alternate solution: use https://brainwallet.github.io/#tx so you don't have to rescan the blockchain for transactions, or do raw signing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bitcoin Core, you must first import the private key using the `importprivkey` console command.  The coins held by that private key will then be added to your existing balance (if any).

If you want to spend those *specific* coins rather than some others in your wallet, you can use the "coin control" feature.  This can be enabled in Settings:Options:Display; when you send coins, you will be offered a list to select which addresses/transactions you want to spend from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Let's say I want to spend those specific coins. Do you know the way to do it with RPC commands?

Answer (score 0):

For RPC you can do a raw transaction where you can specify which inputs to use.  First **listunspent** then **createrawtransaction**, then sign and transmit to the network.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions